# Make async code wait for end before executing

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have an async function like the one below. Note that the timeout function is just symbolic of other code that runs in an async way. I want the code to wait till each of the series block is done before returning to the final function.

```
var async = require('async')
var param1 = 'foobar'

function withParams(param1, callback) {
    console.log('withParams function called')
    console.log(param1)
    callback()
}
function withoutParams(callback) {
    if(true){
        console.log("withoutParams function called")
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("test")        }, 10000);
        callback()
    }
    else{
        console.log('This part will never run')
        callback()
    }

}
async.series([
    function(callback) {
        withParams(param1, callback)
    },
    withoutParams
], function(err) {
    console.log('all functions complete')
})
```

The output is

```
withParams function called
foobar
withoutParams function called
all functions complete
test
```

I want the output to be

```
withParams function called
foobar
withoutParams function called
test
all functions complete
```

Is there any other async version that waits for the final block to finish before calling the ending `function(err){...` part ?  I am learning nodejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to just move your `callback`:

```
function withoutParams(callback) {
    if(true){
        console.log("withoutParams function called")
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("test")
            callback() //  <-- HERE
        }, 1000);

    }
    else{
        console.log('This part will never run')
        callback()
    }

}
```

Of course you can get the same results without the `async` library by just using promises:

```js
var param1 = 'foobar'

function withParams(param1) {
  console.log('withParams function called')
  console.log(param1)
}

function withoutParams() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (true) {
      console.log("withoutParams function called")
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("test")
        resolve()
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      console.log('This part will never run')
      reject()
    }
  })
}

withParams(param1)
withoutParams()
  .then(() => console.log('all functions complete'))
```

Comment: Thanks, the first option isn't really a good option since the timeout function just signifies a bunch of code that needs to change. Can I however chain promises and async function?

Comment: Regardless of which method you end up with, either the callback or the `resolve()` needs to happen when the async code runs. In that sense the second version isn't much different than the first — just replaces the callback with `resolve()`. But you can definitely chain `then()`s just return something from one and it will get picked up as an argument in the next one. If that something is a promise, it will work asynchronously.

Comment: Ok thanks, lets say instead of console.log, i wanted to return values. Can i put that in resolve(value) ?

Comment: Yes! You can `resolve(value)` and then it will show up in `.then(value => /* use value here */)`

Comment: Thanks so much , if i want to parse both `err` and `value`, would i do something like `resolve(err,value)` and then for displaying can i do `then (err,value) => if (err){console.log("Error")} else{console.log(value)}`

Comment: Not really, for errors you should use `reject()` and `.catch()`. There's some good examples here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Comment: If i want to return stuff (instead of printing to console) from the function `withParams` , how do i chain `.then` and `.catch` across both functions? Thanks so much

Comment: You can return a promise from that function too with `return Promise.resolve("some value")` if that function generates an error you can also use `return Promise.reject(new Error("some error"))` which will get caught in `.catch()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162774/discussion-between-illusionist-and-mark-m).